# What do we learn from Mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, big-picture

I have been doing mathematics for some time now. I am currently a UG in Mathematics and Computer Science. I like doing mathematics but as I progress, I notice that I don't remember certain theorems at all. I forget how to divide/multiply at times. I have forgotten almost all of the theorems that I learnt. 
And whatever I am studying I am likely to forget it soon enough too. So what are we expected to do ? Gain understanding and then move on, the theorems/results don't matter ?

All books on a subject have different theorems on a topic? Am I supposed to read all of them? I can write proofs but certain theorems are listed in the books that I hardly encounter again, why are they mentioned over others in the book ?

How do you know that you have proved a new theorem that hasn't been proved before ?

Comment: Good question, but you should probably modify the title, since it makes your question sound more controversial than it really is.

Comment: I'm afraid this Question needs to be revised to make it suitable for the Math.SE content.  See the [Help Center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) for guidelines on asking Questions that can be Answered in fairly concise ways.

Comment: What do we learn from Mathematics ? About the same thing we also ‘learn’ when eating a delicious dinner, or being in the company of a beautiful and attractive woman: absolutely *nothing*! [We](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematician) do it cause it's fun. All those excuses about its supposed ‘real-life applications’ are just rationalizations we tell ourselves and others to justify our addiction, while desperately trying to preserve some illusory sense of usefulness. (Or sanity, for that matter). :-)

Comment: @Lucian. Beautiful answer ! and so true.